# Will `sed -n` only show output when `p` is used?

Tags: sed

- `sed -n` means only show the result after dealing by command，so i need must add 'p' to show the result
- otherwise `sed -n` will not show the result

Is that right or not？

```
sed [root@ljl ~]# cat a.txt 
1111simon111
simon2222222
333simon3333
444444444444
5555555simon
simon6666666
7777777simon
888888888888
[root@ljl ~]# sed -n 's/simon/lili/gp' a.txt
1111lili111
lili2222222
333lili3333
5555555lili
lili6666666
7777777lili
[root@ljl ~]# sed -n 's/simon/lili/g' a.txt
[root@ljl ~]#
```

Comment: Did you read `man sed`?

Comment: You answered your own question with your code in your question.

Answer (score 4):

At the end of every "cycle", i.e. when `sed` has finished running the final command in your editing script, there is an implicit `n` command which will print the current contents of the pattern space and replace it with the next line of input from the current input file. The script then *cycles* back to the top.

It is the output from this `n` command (and any other `n` command in your script) that will be suppressed if you start `sed` with its `-n` option.

Using `-n` does not mean that *all* output from `sed` will be suppressed. For example, the `r` command, which reads the text from a file and sends it to standard output, will still produce output on standard output, as would the `=` command, which outputs the current line number. Likewise, the commands `a`, `i`, and `c`, for adding, inserting, and changing text, and `l` and `P`, for outputting text in various specific ways, produce output regardless of `-n` (see the `sed` manual for what these commands do exactly).  Errors etc. would naturally also be outputted on standard error as without `-n`.

Furthermore, the `p` command will obviously still produce output, as would the `s///` command if used with its `p` flag (`s///p`), which is what you mention in the question.

The `d` command always skips the implicit `n` at the end of a script when it discards the pattern spaces and immediately starts the next cycle, as does the less commonly used `D` command.

The `-n` option may be invoked in a `sed` script by using `#n` at the start of the script.

Example:  A `sed` script that only prints lines containing the substring `HELLO`, regardless of whether `-n` is used on the command line or not.

```
#n
/HELLO/p
```

The `#n` must be on the first line, and in this script it would suppress the printing of every line, apart from those printed by the explicit `p` command in the script.

Comment: See also the `l`, `a`, `i`, `c`, `P`, `=` or `r` commands which also produce some outputs (also `R`, `F` with GNU `sed`)

Comment: For completeness, may be worth noting that `d`, `D`, `c` commands for instance do skip that printing (without `-n`), and the `#n` that can be used at the start of the script in place of `-n`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks! Did you mean some other command than `c` in your last comment?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to use `p` to print the matched/modified line(s) if you're using `-n`.

From `man sed` (GNU version):

> -n, --quiet, --silent
>
> suppress automatic printing of pattern space

Answer (score 2):

`sed -n` does not mean "only show the result after dealing by command". It means "only print when explicitly asked to", i.e. "don't print automatically".

Usually you use `p` command to print explicitly, unconditionally. In your case it would be:

```
sed -n 's/simon/lili/g;p' a.txt
```

The above is not the syntax you used. This is what you used:

```
sed -n 's/simon/lili/gp' a.txt
```

here `p` is a modifier (like `g` is a modifier) for the `s` command, meaning "*if the substitution was made*, then print the new pattern space". Like the `p` command it's an explicit request to print (so it's useful with `-n`), but it's conditional.